# Installed ubuntu on Windows 11 RAID 1, can't boot, it goes into BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, raid, bios, windows-11

I've RAID 1 on Windows, it's intel RST. I installed ubuntu on it in dual boot mode. Installation went through but system doesn't boot into any OS and it keeps going into BIOS. I'm assuming boot record is totally messed? How to fix it?

Comment: There's no "boot record" in UEFI mode. MBR implies Windows in BIOS/Legacy mode and that can't be simply because Windows 11 doesn't support it. I suggest you check UEFI (what you wrongly call "BIOS") settings > Boot menu and adjust accordingly.

Comment: On Boot menu it doesn't show Ubuntu.

Comment: So Grub wasn't correctly installed.  Unsurprisingly, because AFAIK Ubuntu still doesn't support Intel RST. Maybe you got away by installing it in Legacy mode? Speculating here, of course, because I don't believe you can given the unsupported pseudo-RAID mode.

Comment: Yes, somehow it went to install ubuntu. So I'm stuck here. How to fix it? Can I get into BIOS settings and do something to get back into Windows?

Comment: Perhaps reverse the changes you've made?